# how To set and pass value of variable which also accesible in another View objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

In AppDelegate.h

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *str2;
```

In ViewController.m

```
AppDelegate *c3=[[AppDelegate alloc]init];
c3.str2= @"Hello";

NSLog(@"Output:-%@",c3.str2);
```

Output:-Hello

Navigation code in Tableview didselect method(view Controller):-

```
Class2  *c2=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cl2"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:c2 animated:YES];
```

In Class2.m:-

```
AppDelegate *c3=[[AppDelegate alloc]init];
NSLog(@"%@",c3.str2);
```

Output:-Null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's fix your current approach: the reason some recommend using app delegate to store shared values is that there is one easily accessible instance of it. You never create a new app delegate, but access the *shared* one instead:

```
AppDelegate *c3 = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Once you replace `[[AppDelegate alloc]init]` with the above, your code will start working the way you expect.

However, this solution is not ideal. App delegate is not supposed to be a place for storing shared values; they should be stored in your *model* object (as "M" in MVC, *Model-View-Controller*). [Create a *singleton* model object](http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/), place shared variable in it, and use that shared variable by accessing the singleton from different view controllers.

Answer (score 2):

In `AppDelegate.h`

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *str2;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    _str2 = "Hello"
}
```

In `ViewController.m` and any other view controller that wants to access `str2`:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"Output: %@", delegate.str2);
```

Never create `AppDelegate` object on your own. Instead, access its instance via `sharedApplication`.